# Single Desktop/Space in macOS

Tags: macos

Is there a way wherein I can just work in a single Desktop on my Mac, running Mojave?

Presently what it does is that when I'm working on something and I open a Finder window it doesn't open the Finder window on the Space that I am working on it opens up a new Desktop.
This decreases my productivity since I would still have to navigate instead of just dragging the item that I need in the Finder window into the workspace that I'm currently working on.  I don't mind having tons of open windows in one Desktop for as long as all the info that I need is in one Space/Desktop and that I do not have to have multiple Desktops open.

I prefer to just click and drag a file or jpg that I need on the current workspace that I am working on.  I don't want multiple desktops that seems to be tedious to transfer a file from one Desktop to another

Answer (score 1):

The default is a single Desktop. It only adds more if you tell it to.

The exception to this is if you use an app in fullscreen, it must go on a new, temporary Space/Desktop to achieve this.
If you are in a fullscreen app & need to go back to the Finder, you must change Spaces to do that.

The solution to having a single Space/Desktop is to never use fullscreen.

You can also check if Spaces have ever been generated manually by opening Mission Control - three-finger swipe up gesture, Ctrl/up arrow or F3
If you then move your cursor to the top of the screen, that area will expand. If you hover over any individual window representation, it will display an X to remove that Space.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply.  i manuallyactivated mission control a far as i remember it.  I went to preferences and unchecked all of the options there. now i can easily drag a file from my space to another. I would also take your advice and not use full screen.  Thank you again.  Appreciate the reply